libz does not extract entire gzip file
This (1.4M) can be decompressed with gzip no problem with say
gzip --stdout --decompress ./archiveteam_blip_20150813160102.cdx.gz

It decompresses to 61400 lines of text.
However, with this code based on zpipe.c, the example script given on the libz website (run with ./zpipe archiveteam_blip_20150813160102.cdx.gz, I only get 3000 lines of data:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "zlib.h"

#if defined(MSDOS) || defined(OS2) || defined(WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
#  include <fcntl.h>
#  include <io.h>
#  define SET_BINARY_MODE(file) setmode(fileno(file), O_BINARY)
#else
#  define SET_BINARY_MODE(file)
#endif

#define CHUNK 16384

int inf(FILE *source, FILE *dest)
{
    int ret;
    unsigned have;
    z_stream strm;
    unsigned char in[CHUNK];
    unsigned char out[CHUNK];

    /* allocate inflate state */
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    strm.avail_in = 0;
    strm.next_in = Z_NULL;
    ret = inflateInit2(&strm, 16 + MAX_WBITS);
    if (ret != Z_OK)
        return ret;

    /* decompress until deflate stream ends or end of file */
    do {
        strm.avail_in = fread(in, 1, CHUNK, source);
        if (ferror(source)) {
            (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
            return Z_ERRNO;
        }
        if (strm.avail_in == 0)
            break;
        strm.next_in = in;

        /* run inflate() on input until output buffer not full */
        do {
            strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
            strm.next_out = out;
            ret = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
            assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);  /* state not clobbered */
            switch (ret) {
            case Z_NEED_DICT:
                ret = Z_DATA_ERROR;     /* and fall through */
            case Z_DATA_ERROR:
            case Z_MEM_ERROR:
                (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
                return ret;
            }
            have = CHUNK - strm.avail_out;
            if (fwrite(out, 1, have, dest) != have || ferror(dest)) {
                (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
                return Z_ERRNO;
            }
        } while (strm.avail_out == 0);

        /* done when inflate() says it's done */
    } while (ret != Z_STREAM_END);

    /* clean up and return */
    (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
    return ret == Z_STREAM_END ? Z_OK : Z_DATA_ERROR;
}

/* compress or decompress from stdin to stdout */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret;

    FILE *source = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    /* avoid end-of-line conversions */
    SET_BINARY_MODE(source);
    SET_BINARY_MODE(stdout);
    
    ret = inf(source, stdout);
    
    if (ret != Z_OK)
    {
        fputs("zpipe: ", stderr);
        switch (ret) {
        case Z_ERRNO:
            if (ferror(stdin))
                fputs("error reading stdin\n", stderr);
            if (ferror(stdout))
                fputs("error writing stdout\n", stderr);
            break;
        case Z_STREAM_ERROR:
            fputs("invalid compression level\n", stderr);
            break;
        case Z_DATA_ERROR:
            fputs("invalid or incomplete deflate data\n", stderr);
            break;
        case Z_MEM_ERROR:
            fputs("out of memory\n", stderr);
            break;
        case Z_VERSION_ERROR:
            fputs("zlib version mismatch!\n", stderr);
        }
    }
    
    return ret;
}


Gzip format is different from zlib format. zlib supports both, but they must be handled a bit differently.

@JohnBollinger Following the manual, I tried to call inflateInit2 and pass  16 as the second argument, but now I get a different problem. The script exits normally, but I only get 3000 lines of decompressed data. The actual contents if decompressed with gzip are about 64k lines.

If the answers to the dupe target do not resolve your issue then you should consider  editing this question to focus on the issue described in your comment, including a [mre] for that, and then requesting reopening.  Alternatively, you could post a new question along the same lines.

The documentation says "add". Use 31 (15+16) with inflateInit2() to decompress the gzip format, or 47 (15+32) to decode either the zlib or gzip format, automatically detecting which it is.

Is it possible that the .gz file contains multiple concatenated streams?

@IanAbbott Indeed it does. 21 of them.

Your gzip file has multiple gzip members. A concatenation of any number of gzip streams is also a valid gzip stream, per the specification. From the documentation in zlib.h:

Unlike the gunzip utility and gzread() (see below), inflate() will not automatically decode concatenated gzip members. inflate() will return Z_STREAM_END at the end of the gzip member. The state would need to be reset to continue decoding a subsequent gzip member. This must be done if there is more data after a gzip member, in order for the decompression to be compliant with the gzip standard (RFC 1952).

Upon getting Z_STREAM_END, you need to see if you have any data left (strm.avail_in != 0) or if you can read in more data. If so, you need to do an inflateReset() and decode the next gzip member by then continuing in the do loop.

Ah, I see! I tried calling the inf function twice but I think I must have had data left in the input buffer and that's why it wasn't working. In any case, I also just indirectly learned that gzopen and gzread exist.
